# The one who's being celebrated (e.g., @ a BD party) (sometimes referred to as the birthday boy/girl)

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there another term to specify who is being celebrated - e.g., @ a BD party?

('Celebrant/celebrator' could be anybody celebrating, I believe. But isn't there a term which will specify the one/ones being celebrated?)

Is there, e.g., such a word as 'celebrantee,' or 'celebratoree'  (&, if not, oughtn't there be (the situation comes up repeatedly))?

Thank you.

Comment: Colloquially, you might call them *the man (woman, child, whatever) of the hour*.

Answer (score 3):

**Guest of Honor** would work for either gender at any big party in their honor.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a single word it is ***honoree***

> hon•or•ee (ˌɒn əˈri)
>
> n.
>   a person who receives an honor, award, or special recognition.

Specifically in the case of a distinction or achievement, it is ***laureate***.

> n.
>   1. One honored or awarded a prize for great achievements especially in the arts or sciences: *a Nobel laureate*.
>   *A poet laureate.*